# Converting LAS to DWG/DXF using open-source software?

Tags: lidar, dxf, las, dwg, liblas

Is there a way to convert LAS point clouds to DWG and/or DXF files using open source software?

Also willing to script with Python - is this possible using libLAS/LASlib for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You may use las2ogr (las utility application), but your GDAL libraries must be built with libLAS.
2. Convert las file to txt using las2txt (las utility application) and use ogr2ogr converting CSV file to DXF
3. Convert las file to txt using las2txt (las utility application) and load it to QGIS as a delimited text file and save as DXF

Answer (score -1):

Update: I've written a freeware app for <s>both OS X and*</s> Windows (64 bit editions only) that converts a binary LAS/LAZ to a TINned DXF. It's called `LAStoDXF-TIN` and you can download it here: http://lidarwidgets.com/#!page-freestuff

<sub>*The OSX version of `LAStoDXF-TIN` is commercial now.</sub>

---

<s>I don't know of any open source programs to convert LAS/LAZ to DWG/DXF but</s> there are user-friendly commercial tools found at http://lidarwidgets.com that will convert them to DXF in just one step.

The `LAStoDXFMesh` tool will generate a true 3D vector terrain model for the LAS that you provide and it will also batch convert an entire folder of LAS/LAZ files as well. There's also another tool that will convert LAS/LAZ to DXF point clouds if you only need the points.  Here's a link to some videos of the software in action:  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpKRoJA-KbSouwC5DqgAl1A

---

I'm the developer of the applications mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, but looking for an open source solution.

Comment: I've written a freeware app for both OS X and Windows (64 bit editions only) that converts a binary LAS/LAZ to a TIN'ned DXF.  It's called LAStoDXF-TIN and you can download both the Windows and OS X versions here:  http://lidarwidgets.com/#!page-freestuff

Comment: I just updated the LAStoDXF-TIN application because on some systems it failed during DXF creation.  This has now been fixed and the revised version can be downloaded from the link in my previous post.